# Using Amazon Instant Video from Amazon Prime on Non-Kindle device

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer, amazon-video

I have an Asus EEE Transformer, and am contemplating an Amazon Prime membership.  One of the nice features is streaming video.  You can play it on computer, TV/DVD/BluRay that support it, or Kindle.

Is there anyway to play on plain Android, like my Transformer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can play Amazon Prime videos using flash in the browser. See [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-1413969.html) thread.

Per the thread, you may have to remove the stock Flash and install Adobe's official version from the market, as well as the Dolphin HD browser.

You can rent movies from Amazon, which presumably use the same framework as Prime videos. It would probably be advisable to rent a movie to verify it works before investing in a Prime membership.

Comment: Poifect!  Thank you!  That is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

As of very recently, this no longer is possible. Flash for Android is no longer supported, upgraded or offered by Adobe.

There are hacks available for installing older versions of Flash, but given the security holes this opens up, installing an expired version of Flash is probably a really bad idea.

Comment: Yep, that's what I said. Amazon wants Apple owners, all the rest can buy the Kindle Fire, despite the Android derivation, they have no interest in releasing the Amazon Instant Video app for use on anything but their own device. Lots of Android based phone users can just go elsewhere, I guess. Hulu Plus, NetFlix, etc. Hopefully they'll get to work on HTML5 video streaming soon, maybe that's their plan.