# Fooling a tablet into thinking it's a phone so that Amazon Prime streaming will work

Tags: tablet, amazon-video

This relates to question:

[Using Amazon Instant Video from Amazon Prime on Non-Kindle device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17689/using-amazon-instant-video-from-amazon-prime-on-non-kindle-device)

However things have moved on since then. [Amazon have now released a version of their Amazon app for use on non-Fire Android phones](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.mShop.android&hl=en), and indeed streaming of Amazon Prime is now possible. However the [Tablet Amazon app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.windowshop) does not have this functionality, even though it is running the same Android OS version (as the scores of negative reviews on the app will testify!) There doesn't seem to be a way to install the Mobile Android app onto a Tablet. It appears that they only allow Amazon Prime to be used from their own Kindle Fire Tablet.

Is there any way I can fool my tablet (Nexus 7) into thinking it is a phone so that I can install the Phone version of the Amazon app and therefore enable Amazon prime streaming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the .apk http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/themes/APKMirror/download.php?id=2395 *Note: Make sure you enable installing from* ***Unknown Sources*** *from* ***Settings>Security***.

If you cannot install the apk, you will have to root your tablet. You can probably find a guide at forum.xda-developers.com

1. After rooting your device, install *Xposed installer* http://dl-xda.xposed.info/modules/de.robv.android.xposed.installer_v33_36570c.apk *Note: Make sure you enable installing from* ***Unknown Sources*** *from* ***Settings>Security***.
2. Install *Play Store Fixes* from **Xposed Installer**, from the **Download** screen *(There should be a drop-down selection menu in the action bar)*.
3. Go into the **Modules** screen *(using the same drop-down menu in the action bar)* and enable **Play Store Fixes** via the checkbox.
4. After enabling, open the **Play Store Fixes** app by selecting it from the **Modules** screen in **Xposed Installer** *(or from your app drawer)*.
5. After you open **Play Store Fixes**, set the DPI (density) to **320** (phone dpi).
6. Go back into **Xposed Installer**, either by pressing the *Back* button or opening from your app drawer.
7. Go into the **Framework** screen. **Install** the Xposed framework.
8. After the installation has installed successfully, **Soft Reboot** your tablet.
9. Open **Play Store** and search for *Amazon*.
10. You should now have the option to install Amazon. *Note: If not, try setting the density to* ***240***.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect! Direct install of the APK did the treat. Didn't need to root either.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this quite a few times. I know it is possible to do this by modifying the build.prop file to fool an app into thinking your device is something that it's not, but that requires rooting, and you also run the risk of soft-bricking your device (happened to me yesterday).

If you are willing to take such a risk, create a nandroid backup before modifying build.prop

Comment: This is not really answering the question is it?