# How to let apps think phone as a tablet?

Tags: applications, root-access, tablet, orientation

I have a Phone which has snapdragon 845 chipset on it. 
I've never noticed any lagging issues on this device which is far   better than most decent TABs. 
But because of mobile, i saw some features on ROBLOX is  missing that is appear in Tablet. 
So, can i modify something which may required root access to  bring those features on it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fooling a tablet into thinking it's a phone so that Amazon Prime streaming will work](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89119/fooling-a-tablet-into-thinking-its-a-phone-so-that-amazon-prime-streaming-will)

Comment: Not exactly what im looking for!

Comment: Changing the DPI doesn't work?

Comment: If you are talking about a specific app you should always provide a link to it on Google PlayStore.